# lighttpd 1.4: Include scheme in www-to-no-www redirect config, with path exclusion

Tags: configuration, redirect, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd 1.4.45 on a Debian-based system and have the `10-no-www.conf` (from `/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-no-www.conf` in the `lighttpd` package) in use to redirect "www.*<something>*" to "*<something>*".

In addition, I'm using `certbot` with the "webroot" method of verification (for Let's Encrypt). Therefore, I want all requests to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/*` to not be redirected (so I have a separate webroot for `www.` and the non-`www.` domain, since each one has a different SSL cert, even though the `www.` domain is just for redirection, it still needs to have a proper SSL cert to work).

This is the original content (does not work with https, does not exclude the acme-challenge part):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" )
}
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)" {
      url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" )
    }
  }
}

$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
  $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)" {
      url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
    }
  }
}
```

While this works, it looks unnecessarily verbose -- is there a way to parameterize the scheme matching so that I can do it in a single block instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work by itself, as lighttpd currently does not support schemes other than "http" and "https":

```
  $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)" {
      url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
    }
  }
```

Note: lighttpd added support for TLS-ALPN-01 in lighttpd 1.4.53.  Latest lighttpd at the moment is lighttpd 1.4.55.  TLS-ALPN-01 is recommended for use with Let's Encrypt.